# How to compute second moment of this hitting time of random walk

Tags: probability-theory

Given a symmetric simple random walk on the line starting at the origin such that the probability of going one unity to right and left at each step is $1/2$, I would like to compute
$$\mathbb{E}(T_a^2)$$
where $T_a=\min \{n:S_n\in \{-a,a\}\}$ for integer $a>0$, but I have no clue from where to start. I know that one can compute its first moment using Wald's equality once proved it is finite. Is it possible to approach the question using this result in some way? I would appreciate some hint or reference.

Comment: Using $E[(T+1)^2]=E[T^2]+2E[T]+1$, you can derive an inhomogeneous recurrence relation using the total expectation formula and then solve it and apply the boundary conditions.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of a question of mine by the way (my third question ever). I will put it in the close vote tomorrow if this hasn't either been closed or deleted or answered by then.

Comment: @Ian [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754284/variance-of-exit-time-for-simple-symmetric-random-walk)

Comment: @JohnBarber That's the one.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I somehow managed to misread "$\{-a,+a\}$" as "$[-a,+a]$".