# Expected number of strikes to kill a $3$-headed dragon

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, random-walk, stopping-times

> You want to slay a dragon with $3$ heads. There is $0.7$ chance of destroying a head and $0.3$ chance of missing. If you miss, a new head will grow. $X$ is a random variable for the number of rounds until you slay all $3$ heads. Find $E[X]$.

I get the following pmf that $P(X = n) = {?}\ 0.7^{k} 0.3^{k-3}$ where $n$ is the number of slays ($3$, $5$, $7$...) and $k$ is the number of strikes that destroy a head. I am struggling with coming up with a coefficient for the expression or number of ways to permute successes and failures. I understand that the missing strikes cannot be at the end, and there also cannot be more than $2$ successful strikes before the 1st miss. How to think of a expression to capture the coefficient?

Comment: I suggest working recrusively.  Let $E_-$ denote the expected number of rounds until you lower the number of heads by $1$.  Note that lowering the number of heads by $2$ is then expected to take $2E_-$ rounds and so on.

Comment: I think the coefficient is closely related to the Catalan numbers. The number of heads goes up and down like a Dyck-path and musn't go below level 1 and it starts at level 3 and ends on level 1 (the last slay then goes to level 0). Seem to be called Lobb numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobb_number So I'd say Lobb_{2, n-1}.

Comment: Continuation.. Their generating function will give the expectation as you put the 0.7 and 0.3 to the x part and sum. It surely has a some sort of squareroot as also here: https://books.google.fi/books?id=DmXmBwAAQBAJ on page 116 in talking about the infinite drunkards walk (which this problem is) there appears the $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4pqu^2}}{2pu}$ (similar to Catalan generating function).

Comment: I hope it's okay that I replaced “slays” with “strikes”.  In English “slay” usually means “kill’ and it is a verb, never a noun.

Comment: Yes, it's $\frac{i}{q-p}$! That squareroot thingy collapses into $q-p$. But if you want to calculate something more than the expected value, you have that Lobb generating function to do it.

Comment: @lulu: You need to justify that the expectation exists. See [this comment on a related post on one-step analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/2632201).

Comment: @user21820  True, though in this case I didn't take the technical objection seriously.  In a large number of rounds, the probability that fewer than half of the outcomes are successes goes to $0$.  Much harder, of course, if the probability is $.5$ instead of $.7$

Comment: What you wrote in your above comment is insufficient. You are making an invalid quantifier swap. Since we want finite expectation, it's not enough to have the probability of the output being n tend to zero as n → ∞.

Answer (score 9):

Let $\epsilon_1,\ldots,$ be iid random variables such that $P(\epsilon_1=1) = 0.3$ and $P(\epsilon_1=-1) = 0.7$.

Defining the random walk $S_0=3$, $S_n = 3+\sum_{k=1}^n \epsilon_k$, and the hitting time $\tau$ where $S_{\tau}=0$, you're looking for $E[\tau]$.

It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560867/asymmetric-random-walk-prove-et-fracbp-q-how-do-i-use-hint) that $E[\tau] = \frac{3}{0.7-0.3}=7.5$.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the discussion in the comments:

Let $E_-$ denote the expected number of rounds it takes to lower the number of heads by $1$.  This is, of course, independent of the number of heads you are currently facing. It is also clear that the expected number of rounds needed to remove $n$ heads is just $nE_-$.

Considering the results of the next round we see that $$E_-=.7\times 1+.3\times (1+2E_-)=1+.6E_-\implies E_-=2.5$$

It follows that you expect it to take $3E_-=7.5$ rounds to slay the dragon.

Comment: Can I ask if there is a way to get variance using the same method? So using this method to get E[X^2] somehow

Comment: You can, but it is messier.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754284/variance-of-exit-time-for-simple-symmetric-random-walk) for a discussion related to a similar problem (they have a symmetric process, but that's not a big change).